# To prove a matrix non singular

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image: Here is the question which I am facing difficulty to solve]

I know I have to prove determinant of a matrix as non zero. But how to proceed.

Please guide.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You mean $k^{\text{th}}$ column is $X_k$?

Comment: A hermitian matrix is diagonalizable, and it is easy to show that $X_i$s are orthogonal to each other, and we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are linearly independent, since they are eigenvectors that correspond to distinct eigenvalues. Therefore, the matrix is non-singular.

Comment: How? . I am having difficulty understanding this concept. Please can you explain a bit more. I get a non singular matrix determinant is non zero but how a non singular matrix be proven from  $$  λ1.X1 +  λ2. X2 +... = 0 $$ which will give  λ1 =  λ2= ....=0

Comment: @Sitanshu That's a standard Linear Algebra theorem. You'll find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29371/how-to-prove-that-eigenvectors-from-different-eigenvalues-are-linearly-independe).

Comment: I think the OP is asking how linear independence of matrix columns implies nonsingularity of the matrix.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Yes that's what I was intending to ask.

Comment: You can find a proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529833/how-to-prove-invertibility-of-a-linear-independent-column-matrix

Comment: @Sitanshu Because that's one of the properties of the deerminants: the determinant is $0$ if and only if the columns are linearly independent (and it works with lines too). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79356/using-the-determinant-to-verify-linear-independence-span-and-basis), for instance.

Comment: Yes , I studied if det A not equal to 0, then it's linear independent. But is the reverse / vice -versa true , that is, if column vectors are linear independent, then det A not 0 and thus non singular?

Comment: @Sitanshu Yes, it is.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This helped me in understanding linear algebra better :)

Comment: @Sitanshu Please mark one of the answers as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

A Hermitian matrix $A$ admits the following decomposition (diagonalisation):
$$A V = V \Lambda\tag{*}$$
Where $\Lambda=\textrm{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ and $V=[X_1,...X_n]$. We also know that the columns of the matrix $V$ are linearly independent (proof below), $i.e.$ $\det{(V)}\neq 0$.

Because $A$ is Hermitian $V^TV=I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix., therefore:
$$\det(V)=1/\det{(V^T)}$$
From $(*)$ $$\det{(A)} = \det{(V\Lambda V^T)}=\det{(\Lambda)}=\prod_i^n{\lambda_i}$$
Therefore $A$ would be nonsingular if $\lambda_i\neq 0$

---

To prove that $V$ is nonsingular you can show that in the case $A$ is Hermitian the equations 
$$AV=V\Lambda \qquad UA=\Lambda U$$
show that 
$U=V^T$, and therefore the matrix $V$ is orthogonal:

Comment: The question was whether $V$ was nonsingular, not $A$.

Comment: It is totally true @mechanodroid thank you. I think it is okay.

Comment: I got A is non singular because the det A is non zero. I did not get how det V is non zero.

Comment: @Sitanshu the determinant of an orthogonal matrix is always nonzero, and equals to $1$ or $-1$. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Oh, yes. I got that.

Answer (score 2):

Let $i\ne j$. We have:
$\newcommand\inner[2]{\langle #1, #2 \rangle}$

$$\lambda_i\inner{X_i}{X_j} = \inner{\lambda_i X_i}{X_j} = \inner{AX_i}{X_j} = \inner{X_i}{AX_j} = \inner{X_i}{\lambda_j X_j} = \overline{\lambda_j}\inner{X_i}{X_j}$$

Assume $\inner{X_i}{X_j} \ne 0$. By cancelling $\inner{X_i}{X_j}$ we get $\lambda_i = \overline{\lambda_j}$, and since the eigenvalues of a hermitian matrix are real, $\lambda_i = \lambda_j$. But, this is a contradiction with all the eigenvalues being distinct.

$\inner{X_i}{X_j} = 0$ follows, so the set $\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$ is orthogonal and thus linearly independent. This implies that $C$ is nonsingular.